# access html 5 data attribute in php

Tags: php, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a form which includes

```
<input id="user-id" type="text" data-user-id="" name="message" placeholder="type and send..." class="form-control">
```

`data-user-id` HTML5 data attribute. When I submit the form, I want to use the value of data attribute in a php class. How to access this data attribute in php?

Comment: You mean in $post or via  xmlparser.?

Comment: I want to store this value in db so I have to access it via php in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your user ID should be in a separate hidden field, such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="123">
<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="type and send..." class="form-control">
```

Your `message` input shouldn't have an `id` of `user-id` and shouldn't need `data-user-id` at all.

Data attributes are used by JavaScript. Hidden inputs pass values to PHP that the user doesn't need to see. Neither are truly hidden to the user.

Comment: i do not want to use a hidden field, may be that is not a good practice. I want to use HTML5 data attribute to post extra data.

Comment: @Adamnick I think you are confusing what data attributes are for. When submitting a form, hidden fields are not only good practice, but are standard for this type of behaviour.

Comment: Actually I agree with rybo111 on this, that's a better solution than my one.

Comment: data attribute makes the data private but hidden input just hides data from view, users still can see it.

Comment: @Adamnick users can see your data attributes, too. Try Inspect Element in Chrome, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting this form directly to a PHP script, you cannot access the data attributes. If you want to be able to do this you'd need to listen for the form submission in Javascript, then on submit grab the data you need and post it to the PHP script to handle it.

Here is some example code (untested!), using jQuery.

```
$('#form_name').on('submit',function(){

   var user_id = $('#user-id').attr('data-user-id');

   $.post('form_handle.php',{'user_id':user_id,[...],[...]});

});
```

Where `[...]` is any other form data to be posted to the handler. The handler can then retrieve posted values in the normal way, e.g. `$_POST['user_id']`.

Comment: then in the `form_handle.php` I will access the value using $_POST['user_id'] ?

Comment: I am a beginner and I only know javascript and above code is not working.

Comment: can you give a solution in js?

Comment: Not right now -- just reference jQuery (follow the instructions on their site) in your HTML document and the code should work (though I haven't tested it).