# Moving div Up and Down Changing ID Num using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to change ID when moving the div up and down so then I can submit them numbers to MySQLi...

So basically from

```html
<div id="1" class='col1'>1</div>
<div id="2" class='col2'>2</div>
<div id="3" class='col3'>3</div>
<div id="4" class='col4'>4</div>
<div id="5" class='col5'>5</div>
```

to

```html
<div id="5" class='col1'>1</div>
<div id="2" class='col2'>2</div>
<div id="4" class='col3'>3</div>
<div id="1" class='col4'>4</div>
<div id="3" class='col5'>5</div>
```

or something like that...

HTML

```html
    <div id='items'>
                <div id="1" class='col1'>1</div>
                <div id="2" class='col2'>2</div>
                <div id="3" class='col3'>3</div>
                <div id="4" class='col4'>4</div>
                <div id="5" class='col5'>5</div>

            </div>

    <a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
    <a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
```

JS

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selected=0;

         var itemlist = $('#items');
        var len=$(itemlist).children().length; 

        $("#items div").click(function(){
            selected= $(this).index();
            alert("Selected item is " + $(this).text());
        });


         $("#up").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           if(selected>0)
            {
                jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected-1)).before(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
                selected=selected-1;
            }
        });

         $("#down").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            if(selected < len)
            {
                jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected+1)).after(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
                selected=selected+1;
            }
        });




    });
```

CSS

```css
    #items div{
      width:100px;
      height:20px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      margin-top:2px;
      text-align:center
    }
    div .col1{
      background-color:#000;
      color:#fff
    }
    .col2{
      background-color:#0f0;
    }
    .col3{
      background-color:#00f;
      color:#fff
    }
    .col4{
      background-color:#f00;
      color:#fff
    }
    .col5{
      background-color:#ff0;

    }
```

Everything moves but somehow I need it to change the ID if possible so then it will sort in that order.

Is this possible? If so can someone help me please.

Comment: What's the benefit of changing the element's unique identifier over it's value or another arbitrary attribute?

Comment: @CoderLee It's for a song request system so I want to be able to change the playlist order, the idea is the ID will be submitted to a row in SQLi then I will then order it.

Comment: Why not do that server side? Instead of muddying up your UI id's you could have a table that contains a "sort" column you manage with code and set on initial insert/updates.

Comment: How would I move the songs where I want though? It doesn't have to be a ID just need to submit a number to server than it be in order of what I choosen. Be a help if you can help, I'm a n00b

Comment: A way could be to build out a json object from the server, and use ajax to get it, then use it to render your list. How are you storing/retrieving the "playlists"?

Comment: At the moment it's sorted by ID so the top are the old and the bottom is the new, what about data-* attribute? Can't JS put a number in there and then I can submit it?

Comment: This is what it  looks like, it's basically a request system http://prntscr.com/qy0kga but I want to change around songs.

Comment: Yes, you could definitely use data-sort-position (or whatever your preferred naming is) then target that attribute in you JS to sort as needed.

Comment: Ok cool then it won't mess with the server ID then, how would I code it into the JS?

Comment: See answer below, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take that list of items, or songs in your case, and then iterate over each item whenever you change an item's position. That way you preserve the elements ID but you have an accurate sort number to store server side when needed. In JS you can do some thing like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var selected=0;

        var itemlist = $('#items');
        var len=$(itemlist).children().length; 

        $("#items div").click(function(){
            selected= $(this).index();
            alert("Selected item is " + $(this).text());
        });


         $("#up").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           if(selected>0)
            {
                jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected-1)).before(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
                selected=selected-1;
                changeSortOrder();
            }
        });

         $("#down").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            if(selected < len)
            {
                jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected+1)).after(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
                jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected-1)).attr('data-sort', selected + 1);
                selected=selected+1;
                changeSortOrder();
            }
        });
    });

    function changeSortOrder() {
      var listItems = $('#items').children();

      for (var item in listItems) {
        listItems[item].setAttribute('data-sort', parseInt(item) + 1);
      }
    }
```

With the added function being the main take away.

```js
function changeSortOrder() {
    var listItems = $('#items').children();

    for (var item in listItems) {
        listItems[item].setAttribute('data-sort', parseInt(item) + 1);
    }
}
```

What's going on here is that you grab all those items in your list, then re-assign the sort number of them by iterating over each one. So when you move Item 1 down to position two, you see item 2 now has its sort position set to one instead of 2 and so on for each element in the list.

For example here is what the HTML will looklike after selecting item 1 and clicking -> down:

```html
<div id="2" sort="1" class='col'>2</div>
<div id="1" sort="2" class='col1'>1</div>
<div id="3" sort="3" class='col3'>3</div>
<div id="4" sort="4" class='col4'>4</div>
<div id="5" sort="5"  class='col5'>5</div>
```

See this [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/CoderLee/z0w38mx6/3/) for a working example to better illustrate this.

Comment: That seems to work, once I code the php, I will let you know :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help! If that solves the JS part of it please consider selecting this as the answer. Feel free to reach out/message if you need help with the PHP too.

Comment: Do you know how to read the data-sort to update to sqli?

`$sql = "UPDATE youtube SET sort='$_POST[sort]' WHERE id=$_GET[id]";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Failed to update";
}`

Comment: Do you have a github for your project? And checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32286264/8645002 depending on how you're posting your data that could do the trick.

Comment: That's confusing haha, no it's not 100%  finished ye. I'm so closed with this project, just the data sort going into the rows

Comment: Unfortunately so is PHP haha, can you share the PHP any? It's a lot easier to make suggestions when we can see what's going on. That's probably a good question in and of itself too, "How to post data-* values with PHP $_POST[...]"

Comment: Check out the commented code in the JS section of the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CoderLee/z0w38mx6/26/ for an example of how you could use the technique from the confusing answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207305/discussion-between-mbell86-and-coderlee).